# Управление анимацией GIF посредством JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, анимация, gif

Есть ли способы управлять анимацией анимированного `GIF` посредством `JavaScript`? Если есть способы, то как это можно сделать?

Нужно четыре действия:

1. Отобразить анимированный `GIF` при загрузке страницы с приостановленной анимацией
2. Запустить анимацию
3. Остановить анимацию
4. Изменить направление анимации

Comment: Неа, используйте видео

Comment: Можно конечно @andreymal, не вводите в заблуждение)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach парсить гифку джаваскриптом? Лютое извращение

Comment: @andreymal По производительности будет явно лучше чем работа с видео

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach а по-моему ровно наоборот (хотя бы потому, что видео ускоряется аппаратно). Есть тесты производительности, подтверждающие ваши слова?

Comment: @andreymal Провел ресерч, да соглашусь, видео будет более подходящим вариантом с точки зрения производительности. Спасибо за замечание. Но в свое оправдание скажу что ведь ответ на вопрос "да, можно"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть javascript библиотека, которая делает с анигифами все, что душе угодно: можно стартовать, останавливать, менять размер и пропорции и т.п.
https://codyshop.ru/upravlenie-gif-animatsiey-na-js/
, 
http://krasimir.github.io/gifffer/

Но намного проще найти workaround для конкретного случая. Например, если надо стартовать и останавливать anigif - сохраните один из кадров как статический gif, дальше просто меняйте в src одно на другое. 
А для смены направления анимации - можно создать еще один anigif, хотя гораздо проще вместо анимационного gif менять кадры в JavaScript - сдвигом в одном файле или подгрузкой разных файлов в src.

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий и по правилам форума его снесут модераторы. Чтобы этого не случилось, а Ваша репутация заслужено выросла - есть смысл чуть подробнее рассказать, что там можно делать с кратеньким примером.